# How do I access Web Api from Area View?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

How do I access Web API from Area's view?

I have a apicontroller in the project's Controllers folder. I tried to access the api with the following jquery code in the Area's view.

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'api/retechsysinfos',
                data: JSON.stringify(requestData),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success(response) {


                },
                complete() {

                }
            });
```

When I tried to run it. It will give me 404 error.

http://localhost/blahApp/blahTech/api/retechsysinfos - this is the url that Chrome display on console with 404.

Comment: And what is the actual url for the API endpoint? Generally, you'd avoid relative url in your ajax request so you don't run into this type of problem.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use `Url.Content()` combined with `~/` as a reference to your web root:

```
url: '@Url.Content("~/api/retechsysinfos")',
```

Note that this will work in e.g. a View containing the ajax code, but not in a JS file containing the ajax code (because those are static and not processed by MVC).